# MySQL If statement with multiple expression

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I want execute multiple expressions in `if` statement inside `select` as below:

```
SELECT 
  t.id,
  IF (
    id > 10,
    @var1 := t.id; @var2 := t.title,
    t.title
  )
FROM
  table
```

Is there any way to execute both of these expressions `@var1 := t.id; @var2 := t.title` in a single `if` statement?

Comment: make different if statements

Comment: This is IF() function, not statement.

Comment: *Is there any way to execute both of these expressions .. in a single if statement?* This is possible, especially when at least one of the columns is not nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
SELECT 
  t.id,
  IF (
    id > 10,
    CONCAT(@var1 := t.id , @var2 := t.title),

    t.title
  )
FROM
  table1 t;
SELECT @var2;
SELECT @var1;
```

But user defined variables are scalar values, so you only would get the last values selected for @var1 and @var2, but it would now display the concatenated values.

so at all it makes not really sense, if you have multiple rows